# Complex Shape Generation Issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I achieve XAML design for following image? I have main issue with curve that have applied to white fill area. I want to achieve that curve in WPF. I want to generate shape that contains "Group" text.

[image]

Comment: I am not familer with expression blend. I have it on my machine, but I am design all the designs in Visual Studio. Can you please describe how to achieve in Express blend ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just wanting to know how to make the shape? Or the whole 9 yards of implementing that design in a custom TabControl? Like HighCore said, its easy with Blend using a Rectangle, a Ellipse, select both and do Object->Combine->Subtract, but a whole control template would require a bit more effort.